# Nested #include and error : fatal error: map : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, nested, include, c-preprocessor

I wrote a multiple files program in C/C++ and create library.h and put all of *.h in library.h, Then #include "library.h" same the following code :

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H_
    #include "library.h"
#endif
```

My library.h is here:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H_
#define LIBRARY_H_

#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <termios.h>

using namespace std;

#include "structs.h"

#include "globals.h"
#include "typedef.h"


#include "readfile.h"
#include "writefile.h"
#include "tui.h"


#endif /* LIBRARY_H_ */
```

Please note that I get the following error:

> fatal error: map: No such file or directory

and map is first `#include` file. I commented it, then map changed to fstream (next of map).
When I remove `#include "library.h"` from `tui.h` everything is ok! `tui.h` is here:

```
#ifndef TUI_H_
#define TUI_H_
#ifndef LIBRARY_H_
    #include "library.h"
#endif

//#endif    LIBRARY_H_
//BEGIN_C_DECLS
    void print_menu(WINDOW *menu_win, int highlight);
    void menu();
//END_C_DECLS



#endif /* TUI_H_ */
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It looks like you have either not installed the c++ standard library or your include path does not contain the path to the include directory of the standard library.

Comment: What's a "C/C++" program? If you do try to compile that with a C compiler, its is bound to error out `<map>` and a bunch of the other headers you're including are C++ only. `using namespace` is C++ only (and should **not** appear in headers).

Comment: I removed **using namespace** line , but my err is not differ just a few warning was removed,

Comment: @m_pahlevanzadeh: are you compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: You really should show your compiling command.

Comment: g++ -c -I. -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0  *.c ; g++ library.o writefile.o readfile.o globals.o -lncurses  -o library

Comment: Of course i use make file ,But all of thing that i run ,above commands.